# How to map a set of point in an orthonormal marker onto a circle sector/slice of given angle and radius?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conformal-geometry

As a starter, be kind tome as I'm really trying to understand all this but sadly after all those years I'm still very bad with Math :(

So, here is what I'm trying to do/understand. I've got a rectangle of `lxh`, a given angle of `α` and I'd like to have a formulae in order to project a set of points in my rectangle inside a circle slide of an arbitrary radius.

[image: In this example, the content of the red rectangle should be mapped into the blue circle sector]

In the example above, I'd like to project the content of the red rectangle inside the blue circle slice.
I'd like the projection to look like this:

[image: Wanted projection]

I've read things about conformal mapping but I can't wrap my head around this.

Please forgive me if I don't use the right terms to express my issue and feel free to correct me so I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so someone gave me the answer to this question.

For a rectangle of width `l` and height `h`, a circle sector of angle `angle` and radius `r` and a point in the initial rectangle of coordinates `(ox,oy)`.

The solution is to map the x coordinate to the angle like this:

```
tr = map(oy, 0, h, 0, r)
ta = map(ox, -l/2, l/2, -angle/2, angle/2)
x = tr * sin(ta)
y = tr * cos(ta)
```

`(x,y)` are the mapped coorinates.